# PHP strtotime returning date from day

Tags: php, strtotime

I am using the `strtotime()` function in PHP to display a date from a day field in a database. For example

```
$Day = 'Wednesday'; //- For example

$Next_Delivery = date("l j F", strtotime( $Day ));
```

Checking this today would return Wednesday 17 April but if I check this on Thursday  it would show Wednesday 24 April - Next week

I need the value to be consistent for the week, even if the date has passed, is there any way  to achieve this with `strtotime()` or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I am unable to understand the question properly. What you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It will always return current week's date of particular day.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I am really just trying to show a date based on a day value from a table. I want to say that deliveries from a bakery are Wednesday 17 April (this week), even if this date has passed. So if the user checks on a Thursday they will still be told Wednesday 17 April, in this case they are told Wednesday 24 April.

Comment: @TJ15 see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just `strtotime('wednesday this week')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this week Wednesday`, that will give you correct result.

And yes, `next week ...` and `prev week ...` work also.

Answer (score 0):

This may resolve your issue.

Try this

```
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'tuesday this week' ) );
```